# Error while running apache tika and vision server

Tags: python, docker, apache-tika

i am trying out capabilities of apache tika and got the following error after setting up and running tika and tensor flow recognition server.

I installed using docker and followed these instructions from the documentation

a. Using docker (Recommended)

1. git clone https://github.com/USCDataScience/tika-dockers.git && cd
   tika-dockers
2. docker build -f InceptionRestDockerfile -t
   uscdatascience/inception-rest-tika .
3. docker run -p 8764:8764 -it uscdatascience/inception-rest-tika
4. Once it is done, test the setup by visiting http://localhost:8764/inception/v4/classify/image?topn=2&min_confidence=0.03&url=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Working_Dogs%2C_Handlers_Share_Special_Bond_DVIDS124942.jpg in your web browser.

and got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/inceptionapi", line 237, in <module>

app = Classifier(__name__)

File "/usr/bin/inceptionapi", line 194, in __init__

self.names = create_readable_names_for_imagenet_labels()

File "/usr/bin/inceptionapi", line 138, in create_readable_names_for_imagenet_labels

assert num_synsets_in_ilsvrc == 1000

AssertionError
```

It is breaking with the same error for tika vision video too but image captions API is working fine, can someone please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 1):

The Assertion error is because it cannot download some of the *imagenet* data due to the Tensorflow project moving where they reside, and therefore the data isn't there to be loaded at runtime. Both InceptionVideoRestDockerfile and InceptionRestDockerfile are impacted.

I've created a [Fork](https://github.com/dameikle/tika-dockers/tree/patch-1) with the required changes and submitted a pull request [here](https://github.com/USCDataScience/tika-dockers/pull/2) to the team at USC. Using the updated URLs allows these Docker images to load the model. This in turn allows them to be used in Apache Tika.

Comment: I've created a docker-compose file in the apache/tika-docker project and wrote an [article](https://meikle.io/technology/opensource/apache-tika-and-objectrecognitionparser-tensorflow-rest.html) on my blog explaining how to use it which may be of interest.